# SQL query -data compare with date criteria , exist , value change condition

Tags: sql-server, join, merge, not-exists

```
create table #temp (
user_id [int]  NOT NULL,
date [Date] NOT NULL,
typeid [int] NOT NULL,
fieldid [int] NOT NULL,
valueid [int]  NOT NULL
);

create table #temp1 (
user_id [int]  NOT NULL,
date [Datetime] NOT NULL,
typeid [int] NOT NULL,
fieldid [int] NOT NULL,
valueid [int]  NOT NULL
);

insert into #temp values (1,'2020-01-25',9876,12, 1);
insert into #temp values (1,'2020-01-25',9876,13, 1);


insert into #temp1 values (1,'2020-05-20',9876,12, 1); -- same row as compared with excluding date condition so ignore this
insert into #temp1 values (1,'2020-05-20',9876,14, 1);



output can be #temp or in different table 

user_id date     typeid     fieldid valueid
1   2020-01-25    9876         12   1
1   2020-01-25    9876         13   1
1   2020-05-20    9876         14   1   -- new row and the value is 1
1   2020-05-20    9876         13   0   -- fieldid 13 value is 1 and not in #temp1 so added here with value 0



MERGE
    #temp AS t
USING
(
    SELECT * from #temp1  AS st
) AS s
ON
    t.[user_id] = s.[user_id]
    AND
        t.[typeid] = s.[typeid]
    AND 
        s.fieldid = t.fieldid
    AND 
       s.valueid = t.valueid

WHEN MATCHED  THEN
    DELETE

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE  AND t.[valueid] = 1 THEN
UPDATE SET
        [user_id] = t.[user_id],
        [date] = t.[date],  -- here i want to set the date of the source table of other fields
        [typeid] = t.[typeid],
        [fieldid] = t.[fieldid],
        [valueid] = 0

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT([user_id], [date], [typeid], [fieldid], [valueid])
    VALUES(s.[user_id], s.[date], s.[typeid], s.[fieldid], [valueid]);
```

unable to set the source date of other fields to the query in WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE. is there any way or any other approach to get the desied output?

to make this work, i updated the #temp with the date in #temp1 for an given user.

please let me know is there any other way to get the desired output.

p.s . edited this question to keep it simple and clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is that is possible with `merge`. You can try the following:

```
insert into #temp
select * from #temp1 s
where not exists (select * from #temp t where t.[user_id] = s.[user_id] AND t.[typeid] = s.[typeid] AND s.fieldid = t.fieldid AND s.valueid = t.valueid)
union
select distinct s.user_id, '2099-12-31', s.typeid, s.fieldid, 0 from #temp s
left join #temp1 t on t.[user_id] = s.[user_id] AND t.[typeid] = s.[typeid] AND s.fieldid = t.fieldid AND s.valueid = t.valueid
where t.user_id is null

update t
set [date] = t1.[date]
from #temp t
join (select top 1 * from #temp1) t1 on t1.user_id = t.user_id
where t.[date] = '2099-12-31'

select * from #temp
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca4296da61f0c40d95d1ad2972b83deb)**.

Comment: thanks very much. its working . i am able to to do the same using merge with an update statement before or after . i see in this case also there is an update statement required to update the date . which approach do you recommend from performance perspective ? IMO, your code seems easy from readability perspective

Comment: @Rocky3151 gr8, I think 'join and update' would be faster, but you can set the statistics on, run both the approaches with lager data and can see the difference.

Comment: Got it . thanks for thequick response and  help once again. Have a nice day .

Comment: @Rocky3151 Thanks! Always happy to help.